# Flutter: Find element

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I find the element if my list is like this:

```
toDoList = [
      ["Make Tutorial", false],
      ["Do Exercise", false],
    ];
```

And the method that I want to use is this:

```
results = db.folderTask
          .where((folder) =>
              folder.name!.toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
```

What I want to do is to search the task by using the method that I mentioned above.

Comment: what's your folder? , the question is about how to create a toDoList strurcture like data?

Comment: No, I want to do a search filter function. It's okay someone already answer the question below. Thank you for asking.